# Value of $\sin^2\alpha+\sin^2\beta+\sin^2\gamma$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\tan^2\alpha\tan^2\beta+\tan^2\beta\tan^2\gamma+\tan^2\gamma\tan^2\alpha+2\tan^2\alpha\tan^2\beta\tan^2\gamma=1$. Then $\sin^2\alpha+\sin^2\beta+\sin^2\gamma$

Try: let $\tan^2\alpha=a,\tan^2\beta=b,,\tan^2\gamma=c$. Then given $ab+bc+ca+2abc=1$

Then how I calculate $\sum\sin^2\alpha$. Could some help me to solve it, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\cot^2\alpha+\cot^2\beta+\cot^2\gamma+2&=\cot^2\alpha\cot^2\beta\cot^2\gamma\\
\csc^2\alpha+\csc^2\beta
+\csc^2\gamma-1&=(\csc^2\alpha-1)(\csc^2\beta-1)(\csc^2\gamma-1)\\
\csc^2\alpha+\csc^2\beta
+\csc^2\gamma-1&=\csc^2\alpha\csc^2\beta\csc^2\gamma\\&\qquad-\csc^2\alpha\csc^2\beta-\csc^2\beta\csc^2\gamma-\csc^2\gamma\csc^2\alpha\\&\qquad+\csc^2\alpha+\csc^2\beta+\csc^2\gamma-1\\
\csc^2\alpha\csc^2\beta\csc^2\gamma&=\csc^2\alpha\csc^2\beta+\csc^2\beta\csc^2\gamma+\csc^2\gamma\csc^2\alpha\\
1&=\sin^2\gamma+\sin^2\alpha+\sin^2\beta
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Let $\sin \alpha =a$,$\sin \beta =b$ and $\sin \gamma =c$

And then use $$\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2 x$$

Substitute this in original equation to get 
$$a^2b^2(1-c^2)+b^2c^2(1-a^2)+a^2c^2(1-b^2)+2a^2b^2c^2=(1-a^2)(1-b^2)(1-c^2)$$
Which simplifies to

$$a^2+b^2+c^2=1$$
Hope you can solve it to get

Answer (score 1):

$$
\tan^2\alpha\tan^2\beta+\tan^2\beta\tan^2\gamma+\tan^2\gamma\tan^2\alpha+2\tan^2\alpha\tan^2\beta\tan^2\gamma=1
$$
Multiplying both sides of this by $\cos^2\alpha\cos^2\beta\cos^2\gamma,$ one gets
\begin{align}
& \sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta\cos^2\gamma + \cos^2\alpha\sin^2\beta\sin^2\gamma + \sin^2\alpha\sin^2\gamma\cos^2\beta + 2\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta\sin^2\gamma \\[10pt]
= {} & \cos^2\alpha\cos^2\beta\cos^2\gamma.
\end{align}
Then replacing $\cos^2\theta$ with $1-\sin^2\theta$ for $\theta=\alpha,\beta,\gamma,$ we get
\begin{align}
& (\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta)( 1-\sin^2\gamma) + (\sin^2\beta\sin^2\gamma)(1-\sin^2\alpha) + (\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\gamma)(1-\cos^2\beta) \\
& {} + 2\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta\sin^2\gamma = (1-\sin^2\alpha)(1-\sin^2\beta)(1-\sin^2\gamma).
\end{align}
Expanding both sides we get
\begin{align}
& (\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta - \sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta\sin^2\gamma) + (\sin^2\beta\sin^2\gamma - \sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta\sin^2\gamma) \\
& {} + (\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\gamma - \sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta\sin^2\gamma) + 2\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta\sin^2\gamma \\[10pt]
= {} & 1-\sin^2\alpha-\sin^2\beta-\sin^2\gamma + \sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta + \sin^2\alpha\sin^2\gamma+\sin^2\beta\sin^2\gamma -\sin^2\alpha \sin^2\beta \sin^2\gamma
\end{align}
Collecting like terms and cancelling terms common to both sides, we get
$$
0 = 1- \sin^2\alpha-\sin^2\beta-\sin^2\gamma.
$$